# LINQ - Joining Lists in a linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, addrange

Question is How do a return a List of B with all the entities in children of all Parents without resorting to the type of code below, I was thinking u must be able to acheive the same within a single linq query?

```
Class Parent {
    public Title,
    public children List<B>,
}

data = List<A>

var childLists = from x in x.Parents select x.children;             
List<B> output = new List<B>();

foreach (List<B> b in childLists)
    output.AddRange(b);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<B> allChildren = x.Parents.SelctMany(p => p.children).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var output = x.Parents.SelectMany(p => p.children).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

using nesting

```
from parent in x.Parents 
  from child in parent.Children 
  select child;
```